# Excel Return 0,1 or 2 if cell equals A, B or C

Tags: excel

I have a cell (Say B16) that has a dropdown list with three options, depending on which one is picked I would like Cell D16 to return a value depending, i.e. if you Pick A return 0, B returns 1 and C returns 2.

I have tried multiple IF, OR, LOOKUP but nothing is working. 
Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: What happens if you pick something other than A, B, or C? And if you pick A, what do you return then?

Comment: How have you tried multiple IF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
=IF(B16="A",1,IF(B16="B",2,IF(B16="C",3,"")))
```

This is for a return of ***{1,2,3}***, modify for any three values you would like.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you, looks so simple when you see it.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't like nested `IF`s as they are hard to read. If you want the transformation to be to {0, 1, 2} then you could use

```
=CODE(B16)-CODE("A")
```

This is idiomatic in programming languages using ASCII encoding. You can generalise this if you use `CHOOSE`. If you want {`a`, `b`, `c`} then use

```
=CHOOSE(1 + CODE(E3) - CODE("A"), a, b, c)
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are the values that you want: {0, 1, 3} in your case.

Comment: But what happens when the dropdown list contains `{"RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"}` instead of `{"A", "B", "C"}`? This will be difficult to generalize then.

Comment: @Dan, well, clearly in that case you're moving to a lookup table. But I like to avoid `VLOOKUP` whenever possible. (1) it makes workbooks brittle; e.g. if extra rows and columns are introduced, it can invalidate the lookup arguments without an error being reported and (2) `VLOOKUP` is volatile in earlier versions of Excel, which are still in use.

Answer (score 3):

Make a hidden sheet called `mapping` with the following:

[image]

Now it's just `=VLOOKUP(B16,mapping!A:B,2,0)`. The advantage of this over the nested `IF` solution is that it's trivial to add more options and easier to read / edit in my option.

also you can use column `A` of `mapping` to populate your dropdown list.

Comment: This does indeed work well if you build your workbook in a *very organised* manner - `VLOOKUP` is vulnerable to errant refactoring: +1 all the same though. This also has the advantage that the dropdown validation could extend over the data in what is column A here.